# вопрос по маске EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть `EditText` для ввода номера банковской карточки. Нужно, чтобы при вводе, после каждого четвёртого символа вставлялся пробел, но (!) когда происходит удаление данных из поля, наши пробелы не воспринимались бы как символы и после удаления восьмёрки (на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

автоматически удалялся пробел, и курсор перескакивал на четвёртую позицию (на картинке).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот решение вашей проблемы на общем сайте:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790102/format-credit-card-in-edit-text-in-android

Comment: спасибо добрый KiS )))